# Distinct cycle decomposition and partition

Tags: abstract-algebra

The number of distinct cycle decomposition in Sn is the number of partitions of n. For eg:- If n=3 then partitions considered are 3 ,2+1 ,1+1+1  i.e  total 3 . But for Set of 3 elements ,total partitions are 5. So my question is why we wouldn't considered total5 cycle decomposition instead of 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

The term partition has two different  meanings in mathematics (they are not unrelated, actually).For numbers (i.e., positive integers) it is the total number of ways it can be written as sum of other positive integer (counting $3+2$ and $2+3$ as one the same partition of $5$).
This is the meaning used in counting cycle decompositions of $S_n$.

The other thing is in set theory: Given a set $A$, a collection of subsets which are pairwise disjoint having $A$ as union is called a (set) partition of $A$. This defines an equivalence relation on the set $A$,a nd conversely any for every equivalence relation a set partition arises as the set of equivalence classes.

Coming back to the symmetric group $S_n$ every partition of $n$ gives rise to a  set of elements of $S_n$ whose cycle decomposition, by listing the length of each cycle component including fixed points, matches that partition of $n$. All permutations having leading to the same partition are conjugate elements of $S_n$ (and conversely two conjugate elements lead to same permutation).

Answer (score 0):

Actually $S_n$ contains $n!$ permutations synonymous with $n!$ distinct cycle decompositions. Eg: 
$$S_3 = \{Id, (1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\},\, |S_3|=3!=6$$

Comment: The asker has not asked about the elements (permutations).  Please read the other answer:  Partition $\neq$ permutation.